# Social SignUp Email address field

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a custom policy that allows local B2C account login and login via OpenIdConnect from Azure AD.
When User from Azure AD is logging first time in he is redirected to sign up page.
The issue is that all fields are filled automatically from the Azure AD token except the email address.

Why email address in sign up form is not populated automatically?
The Azure AD token has the email claim with user's email address.